# Headers cutting off of all screens from top

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

initially headers looking fine but when i perform a module within App which has 4 to 5 screen navigation and get back to home then headers of all screens cutting off from top

Answer (score 0):

Use `SafeAreaView` to avoid such kind of glitches in Application.

For more information visit [SafeAreView Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview)

Wrap the root component or the most upper-level View of your App with `SafeAreView`

**An example would be**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Page content</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
 },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Add snippets of your code and screenshots of UI to help find a solution.

Comment: But it would be not an ideal solution. Don't you think?